# Get id of previous select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next structure:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <select id="house-1-room-1"><?php echo $options; ?></select>
    <input type='text' class='name' name='house-1-room-size-1' placeholder='Room Size'>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add Another Room</button>
```

When  `add_field_button` clicked, I am trying to get the id of previous `select` tag, in my case it is `house-1-room-1` with jquery (or vanila js).

I've tried:

```
$(this).parent().prev("select").attr('id');
```

and

```
$(this).prev("div").closest("select").attr('id');
```

And many other combination of above to no avail.

Please help!

Comment: I think you need something like this:
`$(this).prev().find("select").attr('id');`

Comment: Note that to find the id you find the node first.  So extracting the id, then searching through the document with `$('#myid')` for the same exact node you extracted the id from is a big old waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).prev("div").find("select").attr('id');
```

`.closest()` goes *up* in the DOM hierarchy, `find()` searches *down* the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `find()`:

```
$(this).prev("div").find("select").attr('id');
```

The `.closest()` is the opposite, goes from bottom to top. While `.find()` will go from the current place inside the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

find the previous element and find the select tag within that

```
$(this).prev().find('select').attr('id')
```

this should work

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/3/